# Is it possible to publish a website as a subsite to azure using Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, c1-cms

Is it possible publish a mvc website as a subsite to an exisiting site on azure?

Im running a CMS (Composite C1) that is published to azure and i wonder if I can publish a MVC project to the same webrole/instance such www.mysite.com is the cms system and then my mvc project is running as www.mysite.com/myproject/ or myproject.mysite.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can I run my business site that way (www.staffquick.com points to one site and screen.staffquick.com points to another).

You simply need to add a CNAME record in your domain registrar (i.e. GoDaddy) and point it to the VIP (virtual IP address) of your Azure site.  Your VIP will not change if you do not delete your cloud service...so if you maintain it and just update it, you will be fine. Therefore, myproject CNAME can point to one IP address and www can point to another IP address.

I have had my 2 blogs up on Azure for 2 years now and my VIPs have not changed and not a single day of downtime to it.

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of this solution. But i am trying to get to sites running on the same webrole to save money. Your solution will need me to pay for two roles. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://blog.structuretoobig.com/post/2012/01/17/One-Azure-Web-Role-Multiple-Websites.aspx